# What is meant by part (e) of MTW Exercise 9.13 involving the tangent to a curve on the manifold $\mathcal{SO}\left(3\right)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, group-theory, rotation

I asked a specific question about this exercise a while back.  I put this exercise aside until now.  I had hoped I might encounter something that would shed light on the discussion, but that didn't happen.

This is from Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, Exercise 9.13. We have established

$$\mathcal{K}_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},$$

and

$$\mathcal{R}_{z}\left(\zeta\right)=\exp\left(\mathcal{K}_{3}\zeta\right)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\zeta & \sin\zeta & 0\\
-\sin\zeta & \cos\zeta & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Part (e) of the exercise

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the curve $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{R}_{z}\left(t\right)$ through the identity matrix, $\mathcal{C}\left(0\right)=\mathcal{I}\in\mathcal{SO}\left(3\right).$ Show that its tangent, $\left(d\mathcal{C}/dt\right)\left(0\right)=\dot{\mathcal{C}}\left(0\right)$ does not vanish by computing $\dot{\mathcal{C}}\left(0\right)f_{12},$ where $f_{12}$ is the function $f_{12}\left(\mathcal{P}\right)=P_{12},$ whose value is the $12$ matrix element of $\mathcal{P}.$

The part I'm not sure about is $\dot{\mathcal{C}}\left(0\right)f_{12}.$  Is this just an arcane way of specifying the $12$ element of the matrix of $\dot{\mathcal{C}}\left(0\right)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the book, so I'm not sure of the details, but they probably defined the tangent space to a manifold at a point as the set of all derivations (linear maps which eat smooth functions and output real numbers, and satisfying the Leibniz rule). So, saying $\dot{C}(0)$ is a tangent vector to $SO(3)$ at the identity, i.e $\dot{C}(0)\in T_I(SO(3))$ means that it is a linear map $\dot{C}(0):C^{\infty}(SO(3))\to\Bbb{R}$ satisfying the product rule. To show $\dot{C}(0)$ is not the zero vector in $T_I(SO(3))$, you must show the existence of an $f\in C^{\infty}(SO(3))$ such that the value of this mapping on the function $f$ is non-zero. And just to recall, we define
\begin{align}
[\dot{C}(0)]f:= (f\circ C)'(0).
\end{align}
i.e the value of the tangent vector on the function is obtained by composing $C:\Bbb{R}\to SO(3)$ and $f:SO(3)\to\Bbb{R}$ (which is a smooth mapping $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$) and calculating the (usual vanilla) derivative of this function at the origin.

They're pretty much giving you the answer by instructing you to consider the smooth function $f\in C^{\infty}(SO(3))$ defined as $f:SO(3)\to\Bbb{R}$, $f(A)=\text{(1,2)- entry of the matrix $A$}$ (the fact that $f$ is smooth is trivial once you realize that $\tilde{f}:M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb{R})\to\Bbb{R}$, which takes a matrix and spits out the $(1,2)$ entry is actually a linear transformation, hence smooth in the usual vector-space definition of smooothness; so $SO(3)$ being a smooth embedded submanifold of $M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb{R})$ and $f$ being the restriction of $\tilde{f}$ gives the desired smoothness).

---

In this special case, your curve $C$ maps $\Bbb{R}\to SO(3)\subset M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb{R})$, and the latter is a vector space, so one can very easily calculate the derivative of this curve at the origin. The point is that since the ambient space of $SO(3)$ is a vector space, we have a natural isomorphism $\Phi: T_I(M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb{R}))\to M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb{R})$ (any vector space has tangent space canonically isomorphic to itself via the identity chart). Hence, one can identify $T_I(SO(3))$, which a-priori may be defined in an abstract manner, with the image $\Phi\bigg(T_I(SO(3))\bigg)\subset M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb{R})$, and this image is an honest subspace of the space of matrices.

In an effort to avoid mentioning all these isomorphisms/identifications, the book probably made you calculate things as directly as possible using only the definitions introduced.

Comment: I have the book and the exercise is indeed exactly as @Steven Thomas Hatton quoted it. Is the tangent at the curve not simply$$
\dot{\cal C}(0)=\left(\begin{matrix}-\sin 0 &\cos 0&0\\-\cos 0&-\sin 0&0\\0&0&0 \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0 &1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{matrix}\right)?
$$ It obviously does not vanish.

Comment: @KurtG. yes, this is what my last paragraph is trying to address. We're talking about a tangent vector to the manifold $M:=SO(3)$, which in this case, happens to lie inside of a larger vector(actually Banach) space $V=M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb{R})$. Because $M\subset V$, there is a natural isomorphism which relates the abstract definition of the tangent space $T_IM$, with an honest subspace of $V$. If OP already knows this relationship (which I briefly tried to explain in my last paragraph), then this question is indeed a triviality.

Comment: However, if the only thing OP knows is that "tangent space to a manifold is a set of derivations", then it is of course going to be unclear in what sense the derivation induced by the curve $C$ is related to the non-zero matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. So, if the only thing one knows is the bare-minimum definition of tangent space to a manifold, then they have to work through all this extra baggage through smooth functions $f$ and so on (which is what the first part of my answer is about).

Comment: so tldr: the question is trivial if OP knows how to relate (i.e what exactly the isomorphism is) the abstract definition of tangent spaces with an actual subspace of the ambient vector space.

Comment: thank you. I think I see the point now. We should pretend that $M$ is only a Lie group not knowing that is lies inside an ambient vector space. From that point of view your solution to the MTW exercise is quite instructive.

Comment: "And just to recall..."  That was the hook I had forgotten.  The way you stated things is closer to the Mathematical Appendix of https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691033235/gravitation-and-inertia (page 414) than MTW.  It's one thing to read a definition and nod.  Quite another to recognize when to apply it.